# React native example - dispatch?

Tags: javascript, react-native, flux, alt

I am going through [this example on github](https://github.com/mrblueblue/react-native-alt-demo/blob/master/src/actions/MessageActions.js). And I still don't get one thing. Why is there `this.dispatch()` at the start in fetchMessages function? It's working without that as well. So what is the true meaning of it being there?

Thanks